# Golang calls windows.CreateProcessAsUser function how to get Stdout content

Tags: windows, go, stdout, createprocessasuser

Golang calls [`windows.CreateProcessAsUser`](https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/sys/windows@v0.3.0#CreateProcessAsUser) function how to get Stdout content:

```golang
func CreateProcessAsUser(token Token, appName *uint16, commandLine *uint16, procSecurity *SecurityAttributes, threadSecurity *SecurityAttributes, inheritHandles bool, creationFlags uint32, env *uint16, currentDir *uint16, startupInfo *StartupInfo, outProcInfo *ProcessInformation) (err error)
```

I tried to convert the C code of [Creating a Child Process with Redirected Input and Output](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/procthread/creating-a-child-process-with-redirected-input-and-output?redirectedfrom=MSDN) to Go code, but failed.